# pouchdb exclude design documents when using autogenerated uuid

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

When I use an own chosen key I know whether the first character is before or after '_' (lowercase keys, integer keys or on the other hand uppercase keys) but when I use an autogenerated key I do not know.

So how am I able to exclude everything that starts with "_design"?

```
db.allDocs({include_docs: true, startkey: ???});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple solutions:

1) Do not use autogenerated keys. or if you really need them to be random, make them something like `'myprefix_' + Math.random()`;

2) If you ignore (1), then the only solution is two separate queries:

```
db.allDocs({include_docs: true, endkey: 'design_'})

db.allDocs({include_docs: true, startkey: 'design_\uffff'})
```

It's kind of awkward, which is why I opened [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-2227) on Couch.

Comment: I had to do this recently and I believe the underscore in the example above is in the wrong place. Instead, I used just db.allDocs({ include_docs: true, startkey: '_design\uffff' })

Comment: I don't understand any of the proposed solutions. What I did, and worked for me was `database.allDocs({ include_docs: true, endkey: "_design" })`. Is something wrong about that?

Comment: @Danielo515 yes that is very wrong, there is nothing to say the design docs will be the last docs. For me there were about 3-4 docs after the last design doc, so if you use endkey like you did it omits those last docs.